# Is there any open source code for programming a robotic arm

Tags: python

How can I find python code that i can use to program a niryo ned robotic arm to pick and place objects for a summer youth program

Answer (score 0):

On the official website are some tuturials and example code:
https://github.com/NiryoRobotics/niryo_one_ros/tree/master/niryo_one_python_api?_ga=2.136122481.1190361822.1649950621-2006242939.1649950621

Official website tuturial:
https://niryo.com/docs/niryo-one/developer-tutorials/use-the-niryo-one-python-api/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think you can find what you're looking for on this link: [open-source robotic arm project](https://www.hackster.io/tloinny/open-source-robotic-arm-85ea30)